# Extract data using a date range

Tags: excel, formula

I want to use this formula, but with a date range:

```
=IF(ROWS(T$4:T4)>$T$2,"",INDEX(Table4[SKU],MATCH(ROWS(T$4:T4),Table4[Helper],0)))
```

This formula works when extracting the data from `Table4` but I need to extract only from the date range.

I have 2 dates in different cells: `9-1-15` and `9-30-15`.

The data table is `Table4[Date]` and the cells for the dates are `V5` and `W5`.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the `IF(ROWS(T$4:T4)>$T$2,... ` intended to accomplish? What is the formula for the 'Helper' column?

Comment: im doing this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHdftPxQsVE but i want to add date range

Comment: Good luck with that!